# Advance a range of cells by 1 month

Tags: vba, excel

I have a few tables where a column is a date, and I have a button to advance all those dates by 1 month.  The button is tied to the following code, however it does not work, instead gives me an alert that says `400`.  Any help is appreciated

```
Sub advanceDatebyOneMonth()

   Dim DateCell As Range
   Dim DateRange As Range

   Set DateRange = Range("C11:C26,C32:C40,C46:C54")

   For Each DateCell In DateRange.Cells

      Dim firstDate As Date, secondDate As Date
      firstDate = DateValue(DateCell.Value)
      secondDate = DateAdd("m", 1, firstDate)
      Range(DateCell).Value = secondDate

   Next DateCell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
Range(DateCell).Value = secondDate
```

Should be:

```
DateCell.Value = secondDate
```

As DateCell is already a range

Comment: Yup that totally makes sense, didnt see that, thanks